# How to handle "Undefined control sequence. \setmainfont" in Ubuntu 22.04 with TeXStudio and MikTeX

Tags: luatex

I've been getting the error `Undefined control sequence. \setmainfont` while compiling a simple MWE.

I am using TeXStudio 4.2.1 on Ubuntu 22.04 and have the following font installed: `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-beng-extra/Ani.ttf`

This is my mwe:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{emerald}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{luaotfload}
\setmainfont{Ani}
\geometry{a4paper,left=20mm,right=20mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm}
\begin{document}
    hello
\end{document}
```

And this is an extract from the log file:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \setmainfont 
             
l.14 \setmainfont
               {ani}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: that is a `fontspec` command but you have not loaded the package

Comment: You are correct. Such a stupid mistake. I deleted it sometime accidentally. :(